# How to stop the interval after changing all three messages?

Tags: javascript

I need to stop the interval after changing all messages but I can't. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textos = ["Hi", "Fine?", "0"];
    var atual = 0;
    $('#display').text(textos[atual++]);
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#display').fadeOut(function() {
            if (atual >= textos.length) atual = 0;
            $('#display').text(textos[atual++]).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 10);
});
</script>
```

Comment: The whole thing is a script. What part are you looking to stop? If you're looking to stop the interval, it needs to be stored in a variable so you know which interval to clear.

Comment: You need to figure out what "all messages" means, and then create a condition to clear the interval when that is reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use for loop? or put this in a var and cleat when needed

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var textos = ["Hi", "Fine?", "0"];
        var atual = 0;
      // here
        var intervalId;
        $('#display').text(textos[atual++]);
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            $('#display').fadeOut(function() {
                if (atual >= textos.length) {
            // clear
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                } else {
                    $('#display').text(textos[atual++]).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

to keep last one try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textos = ["Hi", "Fine?", "0"];
    var atual = 0;
    var intervalId;

    $('#display').text(textos[atual++]);
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (atual >= textos.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {
            $('#display').fadeOut(function() {
                $('#display').text(textos[atual++]).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

without animations

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textos = ["Hi", "Fine?", "terwer", "ewrew rwer", "sdfdsf"];
    var index = 0;

    function showText() {
        if (index >= textos.length) {
            return;
        }

        var text = textos[index];
        $('#display').append(text + ' ');

        setTimeout(function() {
            removeText(text);
        }, 4000);

        index++;
        setTimeout(showText, 1000);
    }

    function removeText(text) {
        var elements = $('#display').children();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = $(elements[i]);
            if (element.text().trim() == text) {
                element.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    showText();
});
```

Comment: How do I keep the value 0 at the end? Because when I put the script my display 
disappears

Comment: add a textos.length - 1 condition

Comment: Thanks a lot I put (atual >= textos.length - 0) and worked

Comment: Just one more thing if you don't mind. How do I disable the opacity effect?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp is jQuery effects give a try to append prepend https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Comment: I was only able to do this with .fadeIn() putting .fadeIn(0) but when I a try to do this with .fadeOut doens't work

Comment: try the last one, not tested

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work but I managed to fix I changed $('#display').fadeOut(function() { per $('#display').fadeIn(function() { in the second code

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to stop the interval, then you can use `clearInterval()`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textos = ["Hi", "Fine?", "0"];
    var atual = 0;
    $('#display').text(textos[atual++]);
    let myinterval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#display').fadeOut(function() {
            if (atual >= textos.length) atual = 0;
            $('#display').text(textos[atual++]).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 10);
    // later when you want to stop it:
    clearInterval(myinterval);
});
</script>
```

you can fined more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval

Answer (score 0):

Use Clear Interval to stop current interval.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        var textos = ["Hi", "Fine?", "0"];
        var atual = 0;
        $('#display').text(textos[atual++]);
       var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $('#display').fadeOut(function() {
                if (atual >= textos.length) atual = 0;
                $('#display').text(textos[atual++]).fadeIn();
            });
            clearInt();
        }, 10);
        function clearInt(){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
 </script>
```

This will help you.